# UILabel inside UICollectionViewCell is nil

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, iboutlet

Label inside UICollectionViewCell is nil while setting value. Using custom cell from storyboard so, not registering in viewDidLoad. Below is my code:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CalenderCell", for: indexPath) as! CalenderCollectionViewCell
    
   
    if let label = cell.lblDayName{
        label.text = arrCalendarDates[indexPath.item] // crashing here thus used if let to avoid crash but it is nil, Why so?
    }
   
    return cell
}
```

Update:

```
class CalenderCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var lblDayName: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
```

[image: In storyboard, UICollectionView]

[image: In Custom cell.xib]

Comment: Check wether reuseIdentifier is same in dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier and in storyboard.

Comment: Is the outlet `lblDayName` connected in the cell?

Comment: Yes both checked, correct identifier and outlet connected as well, else it will crash

Comment: is it going inside if let? If yes, then it’s not label that’s nil. try arrCalendarDates[indexPath.row]

Comment: @TusharSharma no it's not

Comment: Have you assigned cell class to tableViewCell in storyboard?

Comment: @TusharSharma it is collectionviewcell, yes else it will crash

Comment: It’s strange remove the connection and make outlet again, also make sure there is single outlet connection for this label, not multiple.

Comment: Tried but didn't work, I think now last option is to remove custom class and create new one

Comment: did you register the cell to the collection view?

Comment: If it crashes despite the `if let` then an out-of-range exception occurs, that means there's something wrong with your data source. (`numberOfRows` returns a higher number than the actual number of items in the array).

Comment: @NevinPaul no, because I did in storyboard but this is the reason. I registered nib not the cell and it worked, if registering class.self it crashes

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the `@IBOutlet` is connected to the expected `UILabel` in the storyboard.

Comment: It is connected sir, rechecked as well

Comment: This is probably dumb. Are you sure the `@IBOutlet` is connected to correct target `UICollectionViewCell` subclass in this case and NOT in the `UIViewController` subclass?

Comment: Yes shared, custom class also, updated question